# How do you add / remove notification subscriptions from a changing array in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, signalr, subject

I'm using this Angular notification example as a service so that alerts from my .Net backend system can be viewed across the entire app.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-notification-service?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

My alerts will be received by SignalR and I'm having issues trying to work out the best concept for monitoring for different alerts and displaying them only once.

I subscribe to SignalR and receive the data easily enough and have an array of alerts, all alerts are in the array, with a flag to state if active or not.

```
IAlerts[]
```

IAlert looks like this:

```
export interface IAlert {
  name: string;
  isActive: boolean;
}
```

I'm thinking that when I raise the alert I need to add a unique identifier (the alert name) for the Notification so that I can check against that as whether the notification is already raised, then unsubscribe that when its accepted by the user or cleared by the backend systems.

```
error(id: string, title: string, message: string, timeout = 0) {

var notification =
  new Notification(
    id,
    NotificationType.error,
    title,
    message,
    timeout
  )

this._subject.next(notification);
```

I presume when a subject notification is added I'd be able to find the id, and then check it.  But I'm not sure the best way to do this - some Subjects, Observables homework required I suspect.

Has anyone got a good example of how I could do this.  I don't have any working code yet to post, but I'm struggling to find the example that would best suit my needs.

In summary I need to raise an alert and be able to clear it when the user or backend accepts the alert. The alert should be unique. The Array from SignalR will reflect these changes in real time but I need the Angular Service to reflect it.

Comment: So you don't only need a notification for the user when SignalR shows a new event but also the possibility to confirm an alert (so that it vanishes)?

Comment: Yes that's right